Can you replace the characters of an ssl certificate on-screen with all stars'***********' so they cannot do a print screen or hidden camera pic?
Can you replace the characters of an ssl certificate on-screen with all stars'***********' so they cannot do a print screen or hidden camera pic to duplicate your ssl cert and gain access to your domain that way?
Is there a switch in cPanel to do this?

Your question makes no sense what so ever.

Very simplified:
SSL/TLS key contain two parts: public and private. When public part is signed by CA it become certificate. And nobody can duplicate your SSL key w/o private part. Moreover public part is (and must be) visible to everyone who use this service. The only part you should keep safe is the private part.
